# how to convert an audio (mp3) file into a binary file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to convert an audio file into a binary file using js or node.js, as i need it for my project

Here's the code that i have tried. the file got converted but is not in binary format.

```
fs.readFile('bell-ring-01.mp3', function(err, data) {
if (err) throw err;

var encodedmp3 = new Buffer(data, 'binary').toString(2);
if(encodedmp3)
{
    console.log(encodedmp3);
}

//perform the encryption, then

fs.writeFileSync("music.sam", encodedmp3, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

   // console.log(encodedmp3);
});
```

Comment: I'm quite sure .mp3 files are binary files. You probably want to add a little bit more info to your question. You comments say "encryption" -- so are you talking about cryptography or is that misleading?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you are looking for a JavaScript library for MP3s.

You are probably looking for the `ffmpeg` library. You can read a little tutorial on [Medium](https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/javascript-tutorial-record-audio-and-encode-it-to-mp3-2eedcd466e78).  Alternately, you might look at the [Howler.js](https://howlerjs.com) library if you want a simple interface.